# How to get all the streets limited to containing a particular text name in Overpass

Tags: overpass-api, overpass-turbo

I would like to get all the streets limited to containing a particular text name, for all `"place=city"` in a particular country.

I tried:

```
[out:json][timeout:250];
area[name="Italia"];
node["addr:street"]["addr:street"~"ercole",i] (area);
out body;
>;
out skel qt;
```

Problems:

I obtain nodes corresponding to addresses. What I would like to obtain are the unique street axes.
On the other hand, I don't know how to filter the `"place=city"` tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's is because you are searching by `node` instead of `way`. And you are serching for addresses, not for streets names. Try https://overpass-turbo.eu/s/1J6d:

```json
[out:json][timeout:250];
area[name="Italia"];
way["highway"]["name"~"ercole",i] (area);
out body;
>;
out skel qt;
```

If you would like to crop your search only to specific cities, then something like would work:

```json
[out:json][timeout:250];
(
{{geocodeArea:Roma}};
{{geocodeArea:Milano}};
);
foreach->.c(
    way["highway"]["name"~"ercole", i](area.c);
    (._;>;);
    out body;
);
(._;>;);
out skel qt;
```

Please note `geocodeArea` is a OverpassTurbo [feature](https://dev.overpass-api.de/overpass-doc/en/full_data/area.html), not necessary available in Overpass API.